# reference or add dll files to an existing eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, dll, build

Just in the same way a maven project requires dependencies, I have a project that depends on another project which has generated 2 library files.

How would I include these library files or include the project as a reference in order to have a successful build?

Comment: Have you tried to define the folder with the DLLs as _Native library location_ in the Build Paht of the project? Do you get an error at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: I get an error trying to build the project; added the dll to native library location. This project uses ANT build scripts and I am not familiar with it. Finding a lot of missing jar file references etc. But the 'hierarchy of type is inconsistent' error led me to the missing dll's but adding it, did not fix that error.